# Why error message doesn't conditionally render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render, conditional-rendering

**username state**

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState({
    name: "",
    isValid: true,
    error_message:
      "start with a letter \n allowed characters: a-z A-Z 0-9 - and _ ",
  });
```

**handle username function**

```
  function handleUsername(e) {
    const regexp = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{5,32}/gi);
    const name = e;
    const isValid = regexp.test(name);
    setUsername(() => {
      return {
        name: name,
        isValid: isValid ? true : false,
      };
    });
  }
```

**jsx**.

```
<div className={`error ${username.isValid ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
                {username.error_message}
              </div>
```

How can I show the div depending on the username.isValid state, it seems like the condition in the className of the div doesn't react to the state changes.

Comment: Are you sure your code compiles? The type inferred by the `useState()` call expects an `error_message`, but none is provided in the `setUsername()` call inside `handleUsername`.

Comment: @MathiasFalkenberg, you're right, I forgot to restructure the state object in the setState()

Comment: I meant *destructure)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ternary operator` if `username.isValid` is `falsy` value then it will render else not as:

```
  {!username.isValid ? (
    <div className="error">
      {username.error_message}
    </div>
  ) : null}
```

You can see this [`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-tom-jfgxem?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: In this case, you could return `className="error"`

Comment: Or simply: `{!userName.valid && <div className="error hidden">{username.error_message}</div>}`

However, there may be a reason why the OP wants to add a class rather than not render the element at all, in which case this is not what they want

Answer (score 0):

The confusions is I just forgot to destructure the object when setting the new state into handleUsername function:

```
function handleEmail(e) {
    const regexp = new RegExp(
      /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1,}))$/
    );
    const currentEmail = e;
    const isValid = regexp.test(currentEmail);
    setEmail(() => {
      return {
        ...email,
        address: currentEmail,
        isValid: isValid ? true : false,
      };
    });
  }
```